# How to get from address using ethClient in go ethereum?

Tags: go-ethereum

How do I get `from` address using ethClient? just like http JSON RPC-API always contains the `from` address.

I tried something like below

```
for _, txHeader := range block.Transactions() {
    transaction, isPending, err := client.TransactionByHash(context.Background(), txHeader.Hash())
    msg, err := transaction.AsMessage(types.NewEIP155Signer(transaction.ChainId(), nil)
    fmt.Println(msg.From().Hex())
}
```

It passes through some transactions but then it also fails with some transactions with an error message saying `transaction not supported`. And some transactions it just says `exit 1` why is getting `from` Address so complicated in go ethereum..the json RPC API `eth_getTransactionByHash` always has the `from` like below

```
// Request
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_getTransactionByHash","params":["0x88df016429689c079f3b2f6ad39fa052532c56795b733da78a91ebe6a713944b"],"id":1}'

// Result
{
  "jsonrpc":"2.0",
  "id":1,
  "result":{
    "blockHash":"0x1d59ff54b1eb26b013ce3cb5fc9dab3705b415a67127a003c3e61eb445bb8df2",
    "blockNumber":"0x5daf3b", // 6139707
    "from":"0xa7d9ddbe1f17865597fbd27ec712455208b6b76d",
    "gas":"0xc350", // 50000
    "gasPrice":"0x4a817c800", // 20000000000
    "hash":"0x88df016429689c079f3b2f6ad39fa052532c56795b733da78a91ebe6a713944b",
    "input":"0x68656c6c6f21",
    "nonce":"0x15", // 21
    "to":"0xf02c1c8e6114b1dbe8937a39260b5b0a374432bb",
    "transactionIndex":"0x41", // 65
    "value":"0xf3dbb76162000", // 4290000000000000
    "v":"0x25", // 37
    "r":"0x1b5e176d927f8e9ab405058b2d2457392da3e20f328b16ddabcebc33eaac5fea",
    "s":"0x4ba69724e8f69de52f0125ad8b3c5c2cef33019bac3249e2c0a2192766d1721c"
  }
}
```

How can I get the `from` address in the easiest fashion using `ethClient`?

Comment: Hello. You should provide the code that you use to send the transaction. The from is the address that should be the sender of the transaction.

Comment: I am not sending any transactions. I am just subscribing to new blocks using ethClient and for each block I get I pull all the transactions which is the for loop above.

Comment: @user1870400 if you are not sending transactions or calls, why would you need to know the from address ?

Comment: building a dapp

Comment: I just want the same thing as the curl command where even though I am not a sender i get the from address except I am using ethClient

Comment: since the From address is derived from the signature, and for every transaction type there is a different way to sign it, you need to check for transaction types, use this call: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c6195623138a995e5c8ec700ba2b0aa3f605951d/core/types/transaction.go#L249 . You are forcing all transactions to be of type EIP155 , not all of them are of this type. EIP155 type was introduced in 2017 so all transactions prior that will fail to decode

Comment: the From address is a modified Public key, so the signature encodes the public key but there are many ways to format the signature (like prepending 1 byte to it and etc)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code if it helps:

```
var bnum := int(1100000) // sample block number


var head *types.Header
ctx := context.Background()
var raw json.RawMessage
err := rpcclient.CallContext(ctx, &raw,"eth_getBlockByNumber", hexutil.EncodeBig(big.NewInt(int64(bnum))),true)
if err != nil {
    return common.Hash{},head,make([]*MyTX,0,0),err
}   
var body rpcBlock
err = json.Unmarshal(raw, &body);
if err != nil {
    Error.Printf("Error unmarshalling transactions of the block: %v\n",err)
    return common.Hash{},head, make([]*MyTX,0,0),err
}   
err = json.Unmarshal(raw,&head)
if err!= nil {
    Error.Printf("Error unmarshalling hash of the block: %v\n",err)
    return body.Hash,head,make([]*MyTX,0,0),err
}   
txs := make([]*MyTX, len(body.Transactions))
for i, tx := range body.Transactions {
    mytx := new(MyTX)
    mytx.BlockNum = bnum
    mytx.TxHash = tx.txExtraInfo.Hash.String()
    mytx.From = tx.txExtraInfo.From.String()
    if tx.tx.To() != nil {
        mytx.To  = tx.tx.To().String()
    } else {
        mytx.CtrctCreate = true
        mytx.To = "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
    }
    mytx.Value = tx.tx.Value().String()
    mytx.Input = tx.tx.Data()
    mytx.GasPrice = tx.tx.GasPrice().String()
    txs[i]=mytx
}   
return txs
```

---- types

```
type txExtraInfo struct {
    BlockNumber *string         `json:"blockNumber,omitempty"`
    BlockHash   *common.Hash    `json:"blockHash,omitempty"`
    From        *common.Address `json:"from,omitempty"`
    Hash        *common.Hash    `json:"hash,omitempty"`
}
type rpcBlock struct {
    Hash         common.Hash      `json:"hash"`
    Transactions []rpcTransaction `json:"transactions"`
    UncleHashes  []common.Hash    `json:"uncles"`
}
type receiptCallResult struct {
    receipt     *types.Receipt
    err         error
    idx         int
}
type rpcTransaction struct {
    tx *types.Transaction
    txExtraInfo
}

type MyTX struct {   

    BlockNum            int64
    GasUsed             int64
    TimeStamp           int64
    TxIndex             int32
    NumLogs             int32
    CtrctCreate         bool
    GasPrice            string
    TxHash              string
    From                string
    To                  string
    Value               string
    Input               []byte
}
```

/* copied and modified from original ethereum sources, for speed */

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this. few questions

1. Where do I get the `bnum` from?
2. I want to subscribe to newBlocks via websocket?
3. how many network calls does this code make to get all transactions in a block? since you are iterating through body of transactions can I assuming it is making one network call or a network call for each transaction?

Comment: bnum is the block you want to download (I updated the answer)

Comment: this code doesn't support events. Internally in Geth the new blocks are being intercepted by listening to chain events listed here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/c6195623138a995e5c8ec700ba2b0aa3f605951d/core/events.go#L43

Comment: the problem with using events is that you can miss one event and the integrity of your database will be lost. That's why I opted to dismiss all the subscription functionality in Geth and go for my own validation at the parent hash level.

Comment: Every time you receive a block you validate that parent hash (of the block yhou are processing currently) matches the hash of the previous block and this way you guarantee 100% that you won't miss any chain split if it happens, and they happen twice or three times a day

Comment: it is way much easier and clean.

Comment: 3) no, the code in the answer makes the download of the entire block +  all of its transactions in a single RPC request, that's why it is fast. I am iterating just to output them in my own transaction object and stuff them in a slice

Comment: I don't have a block number so should I just go with 1100000. My app also want pending transactions. with this approach do I need to constantly poll a block after block in an infinite loop? coz I am most interested in new blocks and its transactions and pending transactions and if I loose an event (hopefully not often) I just want to move on with the latest block and transactions

Comment: for pending transactions you need to scan the `txpool`

Comment: got it, but txpool is also event based right? so should I poll for new blocks and pending transactions in a infinite loop starting from most recent block number?

Comment: in the above code `tx.tx` is always nil so getting a segfault whenever that is referenced

Comment: I printed `body` only `txExtraInfo` is there but not `tx` so not seeing a way thus far!