# Why is the TransactionByHash function in the go-ethereum client unable to return the sender?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, addresses, json-rpc, golang

I learned how to get the sender's address from [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/103026/how-to-get-from-address-using-ethclient-in-go-ethereum). JSON-RPC returns a result with a `from` field, which we can unmarshal in our struct.
But I'm curious why **go-ethereum** didn't return `txExtraInfo` from `TransactionByHash`. In my opinion, knowing who sends a transaction is useful information.